# Express-Session is not persisting in production

Tags: node.js, express, session, gcloud

I am trying to run my nodejs application on gcloud production and the express-session is not working as expected. Its working fine in my local dev.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

// var http = require('http');
// var reload = require('reload');


var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var dashboard = require('./routes/dashboard');
var search = require('./routes/search');
var profile = require('./routes/profile');
var ajax = require('./routes/admin-ajax');
var logout = require('./routes/logout');
var administrator = require('./routes/administrator');



var app = express();




app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(cookieParser('mysessionsecretkey'));


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mysessionsecretkey',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie:{
    secure:true,
    maxAge: 864000000 
  }
}))


app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd')); 
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/moment/min')); 
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/lodash')); 
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/font-awesome/css')); 
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/animate.css')); 
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/datatables.net/js')); 
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js')); 
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css')); 




app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
app.use('/search', search);
app.use('/profile', profile);
app.use('/admin-ajax', ajax);
app.use('/logout', logout);
app.use('/administrator', administrator);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


// var server = http.createServer(app)

// //reload(app);
// server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
//  console.log('Web server listening on port ' + app.get('port'))
// });





module.exports = app;
```

**Middleware - to check if user is loggedin**

```
middleware.isUserLoggedIn = function(){
    return function(req, res, next){
        if(!_.isEmpty(req.session) && !_.isEmpty(req.session.user)){
            return next();
        }        
        return res.send('Session Expired'); //only for testing purpose
        return res.redirect('/');//original code
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "onlineexam",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.16",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "node-fetch": "^1.7.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "concat-files": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-browser-sync": "^2.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.5",
    "reload": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

**Testing Website**

URL: https://node-matrimony-191001.appspot.com/

Mobile:9999999999

The express-session was supposed to store the logged user info and give information on every route.

Comment: Can you set the environment variable: DEBUG=express-session and see the error messages if any?

Comment: In gcloud? I am very new to gcloud like environments and i have no idea how it works?

Answer (score 5):

express-session use

> MemoryStorage

which is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

for production you can use another storage and you can find lot of storage available and compatible with express-session.

The following link contain compatible session store

https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores

Always remember session is stored on server-side.

Comment: thanks..i dropped that project due to this issue and started to moveon with angular and jwt..... the question is if express-session is not designed to production, why its popular... it cost me 2 months of work and now i am starting from scratch.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene - I think, `express-session` just creates a session for you on the server side, but where to store data is the point. they are suggesting you don't sore in server memory. we can use any secured storage like MongoDB etc.